# Control not going inside completion block

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I want to trim video and for that I am using AVExport session and setting its time range property to trim video.But the problem is that the control is not going inside the completion block.I used the following code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *outputURL = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output"] ;
[manager createDirectoryAtPath:outputURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

outputURL = [outputURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mp4"];
// Remove Existing File
[manager removeItemAtPath:outputURL error:nil];    


AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];    

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL];
exportSession.outputFileType = AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A;
    CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(start, 1), CMTimeMake(end - start, 1));
exportSession.timeRange = timeRange;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

    NSLog(@"Hi there inside completion handler");
    switch (exportSession.status) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            // Custom method to import the Exported Video
            [self exportDidFinish:exportSession];
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            //
            NSLog(@"Failed:%@",exportSession.error);
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            //
            NSLog(@"Canceled:%@",exportSession.error);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}];
```

Please help me sort out this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have waited long enough for the exporter to finish? Are you using AVPlayer simultaneously to output audio and or video? In this case, you have to ensure that your audio session is mixable. Have you tried the code on a device? Not all AVFoundation classes work equally well on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. IF the export session is not initialized, the control wont go inside completion handler. And for that you can place condition checking if export session is not null and the go ahead in completion handler.
In my case it was not being intialized thats why it was not going inside the completion block.